# Simplifying to a expression with a double factorial

Tags: factorial, gamma-function, beta-function

I'm currently studying Beta and Gamma functions and there is problem I'm struggling with: I have to write the solution of the following integral in form of a double factorial:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n(\theta)\, d\theta$$
After doing a substitution and integrating I got:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n(\theta)\, d\theta&=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{(n+2)}{(n+1)}\frac{(\frac{n+1}{2})!}{(\frac{n}{2}+1)!}
\end{align}

We never dealt with a double factorial in our class and I don't know why the solution has to be in this form but I would be really glad if someone could help me out symplifying the solution.

Also any hints on how to transform this to a double factorial would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You did something weird.  You changed gamma function to factorial... with the arguments in at least one of these being a non-integer.  Bad!  Factorials only work for natural numbers.  The gamma function is the generalization and should have been kept... not removed.  Your "simplification" did not simplify things and instead made the resulting expression fail to parse entirely.

Comment: As for what final solution you are after... this is unclear.  What makes you think that double-factorials should be involved?  What leads you to believe there is a cleaner expression than the one you have with gamma functions (*after evaluating $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$*)?  Be careful also with the phrase "double factorial" as it is not clear from context if you know what that is... if referring to an expression which has two factorials appearing like $n!m!$, whether you mean an expression with a factorial whose result is also factorialed like $(n!)!$ or if you mean $n!!=(n)(n-2)(n-4)\cdots$

Comment: Ah, I see! Yea I also think that it's prettier with the Gamma Function still in it but the problem explicity says (It's a problem set our prof. gave us): "Write the solution in the form of a double factorial (without the Beta or Gamma function)" EDIT: I mean the expression $n!!$

Comment: I got it now, sry that I left out a crucial detail! $n$ has to be an even integer! With the identity: $$\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{(x-2)!!}{2^{(x-1)/2}}$$ it can be simplified to: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^n(\theta)\, d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}$$